# github actions: notifications on workflow failure

Tags: github, github-actions

We have a scheduled [github action](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/actions?query=workflow%3A%22Self-hosted+runner+%28scheduled%29%22) that fails sometimes. How can I receive email notifications if it fails. At the moment, only the creator of the workflow receives email notifications when it fails.

[image: my settings]

Comment: I don't think that's possible right now. The only way currently would be to write another step in the action to send notification based on build failure.

Comment: that would work. How do I do that?

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/technote-space/workflow-conclusion-action

Comment: Looks like that above link is for Slack notifications only.

Answer (score 8):

you can try this in your actions

```
- name: Send mail
  if: failure()
  uses: dawidd6/action-send-mail@v2
  with:
    # mail server settings
    server_address: smtp.gmail.com
    server_port: 465
    # user credentials
    username: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_USERNAME }}
    password: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_PASSWORD }}
    # email subject
    subject: ${{ github.job }} job of ${{ github.repository }} has ${{ job.status }}
    # email body as text
    body: ${{ github.job }} job in worflow ${{ github.workflow }} of ${{ github.repository }} has ${{ job.status }}
    # comma-separated string, send email to
    to: abc@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com
    # from email name
    from: XYZ
```

Comment: `if: always()` this looks like it will run on every execution of the action, not just on failure, which is what OP requested

Answer (score 7):

You may be looking for this: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#job-status-check-functions

Specifically, `if: ${{ failure() }}`

Answer (score 0):

There is a way using a chain of multiple jobs. For example: Create-Deploy->Debug

Use `needs:[Create-Deploy]` and `if: ${{ failure() }}` for Debug to check the failure, then run your notification code. And put the notification code as the last step of the Create-Deploy job.

This is an example how I have done it for simple Telegram notifier.
Works well.

```
name: Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build-deploy:
    name: Build->Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Sanding the start Telegram notification
        run: |
          curl --get \
            --data-urlencode 'chat_id=${{vars.TELEGRAM_DEPLOY_NOTICE_RECIPIENT_ID}}' \
            --data-urlencode "text=Start! ${{github.event.head_commit.message}} (${{github.event.head_commit.id}})" \
            https://api.telegram.org/bot${{secrets.TELEGRAM_DEPLOY_NOTIFIER_BOT_TOKEN}}/sendMessage


      .... PUT YOUR OTHER STEPS HERE ....


      - name: Sanding the result Telegram  notification
        run: |
          curl --get \
            --data-urlencode 'chat_id=${{vars.TELEGRAM_DEPLOY_NOTICE_RECIPIENT_ID}}' \
            --data-urlencode 'text=✅SUCCESS! ${{github.event.head_commit.message}} (${{github.event.head_commit.id}})' \
            https://api.telegram.org/bot${{secrets.TELEGRAM_DEPLOY_NOTIFIER_BOT_TOKEN}}/sendMessage

  debug:
    name: Check failure
    needs: build-deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ failure() }}
    steps:
      - name: Sanding the failure Telegram notification
        run: |
          curl --get \
            --data-urlencode 'chat_id=${{vars.TELEGRAM_DEPLOY_NOTICE_RECIPIENT_ID}}' \
            --data-urlencode 'text=FAILED! ${{github.event.head_commit.message}} (${{github.event.head_commit.id}})' \
            https://api.telegram.org/bot${{secrets.TELEGRAM_DEPLOY_NOTIFIER_BOT_TOKEN}}/sendMessage
```

I used Telegram  API and the manual curl code here, but you can write your notificator instead or modify mine. And there are lots of ready notifications in the marketplace (Telegram, Email etc..).

It's also possible to get log of the Build-Deploy job using API request with gitHub token to send from Debug it with the failure notice providing what happened wrong.